# How do I detect phone shake?

Tags: flutter, dart, sensors

How do I detect *phone shake* in flutter?
Currently I'm using:

```
void initState() {
    startListeningShake(20); //20 is the default threshold value for the shake event
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: https://morioh.com/p/65f07c3dd096

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fq5zNPJufD0&t=30s

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package for detect shake:

https://pub.dev/packages/shake

To listen to phone shake:

```
ShakeDetector detector = ShakeDetector.autoStart(
    onPhoneShake: () {
        // Do stuff on phone shake
    }
);
```

OR

```
ShakeDetector detector = ShakeDetector.waitForStart(
    onPhoneShake: () {
        // Do stuff on phone shake
    }
);

detector.startListening();
```

To stop listening:

```
detector.stopListening();
```